# How to dynamically set marker icon or MapCircle as fixed size for the current location on map in Qt Quick

Tags: qt, qml

I couldn't find any way to set MapCircle's radius to fixed size while zooming map. Marker icons are used in PlaceSearchModel, but I couldn't make it dynamic. When I zoom the map it becomes bigger, when minimizing the map, the marker disappears.

Here is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.0
import Fluid.Controls 1.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

TabbedPage {
    id: frame
    title: "Web Map"

    Tab {
        title: "Map Viewer"
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            top: parent.top
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
        width: parent.width
        clip: true
        Material.background: "white"
        Material.elevation: 1
        Universal.background: Universal.accent

        Plugin {
            id: mapPlugin
            name: "osm"
        }

        Map {
            id:map
            anchors.fill: parent
            plugin: mapPlugin
            zoomLevel: 14

            MapItemView {
                model: src
                delegate: MapQuickItem {
                    coordinate: src.position.coordinate

                    anchorPoint.x: image.width * 0.5
                    anchorPoint.y: image.height

                    sourceItem: Column {
                        Image { id: image; source: "marker.png" }
                        Text { text: title; font.bold: true }
                    }
                }
            }

            MapCircle {
                center : src.position.coordinate
                radius: parent.width/10
                border.width: 1
                color: 'green'
            }
        }
        PositionSource {
            id: src
            updateInterval: 1000
            active: true

            onPositionChanged: {
                var coord = src.position.coordinate;
                console.debug("current position:", coord.latitude, coord.longitude);
                map.center = position.coordinate
            }
        }
}
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution from Qt's example called Places:

```
    MapQuickItem {
        id: yeahh
        sourceItem: Rectangle { width: 10; height: 10; color: "red"; border.width: 2; border.color: "blue"; smooth: true; radius: 15 }
        coordinate :src.position.coordinate
        opacity:1.0
        anchorPoint: Qt.point(sourceItem.width/2, sourceItem.height/2)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A MapCircle's radius is defined in meters, it is a geographical feature. You found the right solution: use a MapQuickItem. This will keep its size in, pixels 'or screen points).